При парсинге с помощью XPath не возвращается результат
Пожалуйста, помогите решить проблему. Делаю парсинг цен с сайта. Пример страницы. У цены есть путь XPath
/html/body/div[8]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/span[2]/span[2]

Но после запроса парсера мне приходит пустое значение. На других сайтах подобные пути работают. Поставил плагин XPath helper через него выдаёт следующий результат
/html[@class='bx-core bx-win bx-no-touch bx-no-retina bx-chrome desktop portrait']/body[@class='auth_no widget-on b24-on']/div[@class='main_wrap']/div[@class='shadow_wraper']/div[@class='content_wrap']/div[@class='content_right_wrap goods']/div[@id='bx_117848907_309101']/div/div[@class='catalog_item_wrap']/div[@class='catalog_item sw']/div[@class='catalog_item_right']/div[@class='col-lg-9 col-sx-9 col_mob-full']/div[@class='catalog_price_wrap row sw']/div[@class='catalog_price_desc_wrap col-lg-12 col-xs-12']/span[@class='price']/span[@id='bx_117848907_309101_price']

Если просто скопировать элемент, то он выглядит так:
<span class="price_num xh-highlight" id="bx_117848907_309101_price" data-entity="final-price" data-price="2262" data-currency="RUB" style="font-size: 18px;">2 262 Р</span>

Что я делаю не так? Какой путь дать парсеру?
PS Прошу прощения, не являюсь программистом, но возникла необходимость найти решение этого вопроса. Использую batchurlscraper

XPath разбирает XML документы, а не HTML.

@user7860670 что никак не мешает привести html к XML-представлению, я тоже делаю все свои парсеры сайтов с использованием XPath

на какой элемент нужен локатор? P.S. в указанном примере xpath крайне не стабильны, один маленький релиз на сайте, и локатор станет не актуальным

@andreymal Если уж задействовать парсер HTML, то XPath и не нужен получается.

@user7860670 а чем ещё тогда элементы получать? Если предложите CSS-селекторы — так они, как правило, внутренне конвертируются в тот же самый XPath

@andreymal Парсером HTML.

@user7860670 мне это ни о чём не говорит, можно эквивалент нижеупомянутого XPath-селектора //div[@data-entity="price-block"] в том, что вы называете «Парсером HTML»?

Можно использовать такой локатор на цену:
//div[@data-entity="price-block"]
вставьте в xpath helper, увидите куда он смотрит(смотрит сейчас на весь блок с ценой, и на ту цену, которая зачеркнута в том числе).
Локатор только на цену:
//div[@data-entity="price-block"]//span[@class="price_num"]
p.s. старайтесь писать локаторы без длинных лесенок типа:
/html/body/div[8]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/span[2]/span[2]
если добавят/уберут 1 div из пути, то он станет не актуальным
Советую прочитать статейку для понимания, как писать нормальные локаторы

Добрый день, Ruslan. Благодарю за Ваш ответ.  //div[@data-entity="price-block"] теперь парсер наконец смог прислать мне хоть какой-то результат. Выдал блок с двумя ценами. А теоретически можно ли выцепить только одну цену? Я так понимаю есть затруднение в ссылке на data-price="2262"

@Adam, проблем нет, можно подвязаться на класс, добавил в ответ

Огромное вам спасибо. Работаю в закупках и вот решил попробовать упростить себе жизнь. Буду дальше постигать этот прекрасный web-мир. Спасибо Вам!
